# Creating a DataBase Table inside a Class as a Function

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert

I am trying to do the trick of shortening my code not only for readability but also for the customisation of the project I am working on.

I have created a class which connects to the DataBase but am struggling with a function to use that will create a table with columns.

The class looks like this so far:

```
class DataBase {

    private $link;
    private $host, $username, $password, $database;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
        $this->host        = $host;
        $this->username    = $username;
        $this->password    = $password;
        $this->database    = $database;

        $this->link = mysql_connect($this->host, $this->username, $this->password)
            OR die("There was a problem connecting to the database.");

        mysql_select_db($this->database, $this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem selecting the database.");

        return true;
    }

    public function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        mysql_close($this->link)
            OR die("There was a problem disconnecting from the database.");
    }
}
```

As you can see the method of query has already been added. An example of how its run is:

```
$db = new DataBase('localhost',$user,$pass,$name);
$db->query('SELECT * FROM table WHERE id="0"');
```

Could anyone possible sent me some code to add the function to add the Inserting table? I have tried this:

```
public function create_table($t_data) {
    $result = $t_data;
    if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
    return $result;
}
```

Usage:

```
$t_data = 'CREATE TABLE log_users(
     uid VARCHAR(1024) NOT NULL,
     username VARCHAR(33) NOT NULL,
     password VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
     admin VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 0,
     key VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
     constant VARCHAR(1) DEFAULT 0)';

 $db->create_table($t_data);
```

Comment: Hey, your current `query` function is extremely susceptible to an SQL Injection attack, you do not sanitise or prepare your query so an attacker could easily destroy or compromise your database.   You are also using the `mysql` library which has been deprecated for years, you should at least be using `mysqli` or better yet `PDO`.   PDO will save you a lot of headaches and I have written a basic framework here for a DB class which handles SQL injection attacks https://github.com/alexmk92/ASFramework/blob/master/app/core/models/Database.php

Comment: @Alex Thankyou so much! Thats actually what I needed! I will keep a link in the source code for this!

Comment: Question, how would I use this? I'm not used to SQLi. Would it be:

$db = new Database();
$db->fetch('SELECT FROM * table');

& how would I create a table with these? Also, thank-you! @Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking at `MySQLi` or `PDO` since you're using the deprecated function `mysql` which is vulnerable as it stands right now. I have updated your class (not tested) to get you started. This also fixes your original issue of not being able to create a table.

```
class DataBase {

    private $link;
    // May not need these, see updated __construct method
    private $host, $username, $password, $database;

    public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $database){
        // Unless you need them elsewhere, no reason to set $this->host, $this->username, etc...you can just access directly like below
        $this->link = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);

        // Check connection (which also checks selection of database)
        if ($this->link->connect_error) {
            die("Connection failed: " . $this->link->connect_error);
        }
    }

    // You will need to research and update this to work with mysqli (right now it's ripe for SQL injection)!
    public function query($query) {
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        if (!$result) die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
        return $result;
    }

    // This method will create a table based on the SQL you send it
    public function create_table($sql) {
        if ($this->link->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            return "Table created successfully";
        } else {
            return "Error creating table: " . $this->link->error;
        }
    }

    // Close connection
    public function __destruct() {
        $this->link->close();
    }
}
```